# SCons build with multiple environments

Tags: python, c++, fortran, scons, gfortran

**Short version**
Is it possible to build a SCons environment before the SConstruct script exits?

**Long version**
I'm porting some software from Windows to Linux.  On Windows, it builds in Visual Studio 2013, using MSVC++ and Intel Fortran.  On Linux, we're building it with g++ and gfortran.

I've written a Python script that reads a Visual Studio project file (either .vcxproj for the C++ code or .vfproj for the Fortran) and executes the relevant SCons builders to create the build.  My SConstruct file then basically looks like this:

```
def convertVSProjectFile(filename):
    ...

projects = [ 'Source/Proj1/Proj1.vcxproj',
             'Source/Proj2/Proj2.vcxproj',
             'Source/Proj3/Proj3.vfproj',
             ...
            ];
for p in projects:
    convertVSProjectFile(filename)
```

In time this will be reworked to interpret the .sln file rather than listing the projects manually.

For the C++ code, this works fine.  It's a problem for the Fortran code, though.  The problem comes up where files in two separate projects refer to the same Fortran module.  The Fortran scanner spots this and makes the module's source file a dependency of both targets.  However, the FORTRANMODPATH construction variable is set differently for the two targets.  SCons warns that the same target is built twice with the same builder, but then seems to just pick one of them more or less at random, making it hard to predict where to .mod file will end up.

I can think of a few ways of fixing this:
 - Construct each environment separately, build it, then move on to the next one.  But I don't know if there's a way of doing this.
 - Set the FORTRANMODPATH for each object file rather than each project.  Then the .mod file can go in the object folder for the source file instead of all the .mod files for a project going in the same folder.  But I can't spot a way of doing this either.  Could I achieve this by creating a new `Environment` for every source file?
 - Anything else anyone can come up with.

Comment: Can't you do `objs += env.Object(target=...,  source=..., FORTRANMODPATH=...)`?

Comment: After reading your descriptions above (short and long version) it's still unclear to me, whether the build stops with an error (you say you have to fix this) or simply emits a warning that a target is built from different environments (but with the same action). In the latter case, you shouldn't worry...I guess your Builders pick up the module as a dependency for each of the sub-projects, that's why it gets added twice? Finally, SCons doesn't build environments, but single targets (file-based)...so the answer to your actual question would have to be a plain "No".

Comment: Yes, it exits with an error.  Suppose A and B both depend on C.  A and B are from different VS projects, projA and projB.  While building projA, C gets built and the .mod file gets put in the projA module directory.  Then we build B and scons thinks C has already been built so doesn't rebuild it.  But now we're using projB's module directory for modules and C.mod isn't there, so the build fails.

Comment: I guess another solution would be to say to SCons, "I'm adding this target twice because I really do want it to be built twice."  But I don't know of a way of doing that (either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to specify the environment variables for each target

```
objs += env.Object(target=..., source=..., FORTRANMODPATH=...)
```

SCons will see the second use has different `FORTRANMODPATH` and should rebuild it as necessary.